# Using ADB2C how to force credential re-validation for specific application pages

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an application where certain pages with extremely sensitive data require the user to re-validate their credentials before use.

The users are already authenticated using azure adb2c.

I don't want to log the user out when they reach this page, but need them to re-enter their credentials to access functionality on the page (eg like you might see in online banking apps).

I will know who the user is, so need to ensure the entered credentials match the logged in user.

One approach I can see is to open a new browser window, navigate to b2c sign in, and (presumably possible) apply a policy that prevents 'remember me' behaviour.  I could then extract the signed-in identity from that window and check it against my real logged-in user.

However that feels overly clunky and there should be an elegant native way to achieve this.  I can't find anything suggesting this is possible in adb2c docs - is there a recommended approach to solving this challenge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this by creating Custom Policies in AD B2C.

The key of sending data to Azure AD B2C custom policy is to package the data into a JWT token as claims (`id_token_hint`). In this case, we can **send the user's email address** to Azure B2C Policy. Sending JWT token requires to host the necessary metadata endpoints required to use the "`id_token_hint`" parameter in Azure AD B2C. You can refer to [Define an ID token hint technical profile in an Azure Active Directory B2C custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint).

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link/policy/SignInWithMagicLink.xml) sample of Magic Link Custom Policy published by PG.